# PHP and MySQL - display contnet of column between certain numerical values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and PHP but was wondering if someone could help me with a little project I'm doing for my boss.

I have a SQL database (MyDB) and a table in there (mytable) with two columns - the first column (index) is an auto-incrementing integer from 1-10, the second column (date) has different dates and timestamps in the format of `Year-month-day time` `2013-04-12 1326`

I'm trying to create a simple PHP page that first gets the current date (easy enough) then looks at the table and shows the number of rows that fall within yesterday's date. For example, if I have 3 rows with `2013-04-11 XXXX` and 2 rows with `2013-04-12 XXXX` (and today is the 12th April 2013) the page will display `3`. (The time is not important but we can't remove it from the table as it's auto created by one of the other staff's programs and he refuses to change it).

So far I've got my php page, done a connection to the DB and defined two variables:

```
$startdate = date('Y'."-".'n'."-".'d'." "."0000");
$enddate = date('Y'."-".'n'."-".'d'." "."2359");
```

As the timestamp doesn't matter I've gone for the min/max possible on the variables. I realise this will only give the current date, trying to work out how to get it to display the previous day as the date in the variable.

Now I'm trying to create a sql query that will count the number of rows where the date field falls within the startdate and enddate variables (-1 day) but not too sure where to start or how this would look. I then need to output this as a variable in PHP so I can echo it later in the page.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Hope any of this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a query with no params to do this (if its always just yesterday).

```
SELECT * FROM <table>
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(<date column>,'%j-%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%j-%Y');
```

Date functions in the where clause might not be super awesome performance wise